# Добавление библиотек C++ в VSC

Tags: c++, библиотеки

При подключении библиотеки iostream в Visual Studio Code выдает такие ошибки.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Расширение на язык скачано. Как добавить стандартные библиотеки С++ в этот редактор? Или только скачивать VS 2019? В чем вообще разница этих двух редакторов?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: я спрашиваю как исправить ошибки. VSC не видит стандартные библиотеки срр.

Comment: VS 2019 - это IDE, VSC - это браузерный текстовый редактор. Расширение для работы с С++ для VSC не включает в себя компилятор и прочие инструменты, их надо самостоятельно ставить отдельно и четко знать, как ими пользоваться.

Comment: Понятно. А как ставить компилятор и инструменты, включая библиотеки?

Comment: [C/C++ for Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp)